# Delete from select in sql server 2000?

Tags: sql, select, sql-server-2000, sql-delete

I want to delete anything that is returned by this select query:

```
SELECT  u.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  userName, groupId, MAX(userId) AS maxId
        FROM    userTable
    where userName <> '' and userName is not null
        GROUP BY
                userName, groupId
        HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
        ) q
JOIN    userTable u
ON      u.userName = q.userName
        AND u.groupId= q.groupId
        AND u.userId <> q.maxId)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just replace `SELECT  u.*` with `DELETE U`

Answer (score 10):

Structure your delete like this:

```
DELETE U
FROM U ...
JOIN Q ...
WHERE Foo ...
```

Or, if you already have a spiffy query in hand, you can do this:

```
DELETE Usertable WHERE userId IN (
   SELECT UserID FROM ... /* big complex query here */
)
```